# How to enable TAB in KSH script

Tags: bash, shell, tabs, ksh

I am using KSH in my unix environment, and TAB key is not working for autocomplete. Can I enable TAB in KSH same as BASH shell?

Comment: Which version do you use? `echo $KSH_VERSION`

Comment: The above command was not working as KSH version is very outdated, I used this to get 
Command ->  "strings /bin/ksh | grep Version | tail -2 "
o/p -> Version M-11/16/88i

Comment: According to changelog it is capable to use tab completion. ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!original/comp.unix.shell/8s2GFjK-d6Y/WY1bUHAOlCMJ )

Answer (score 1):

No. you can't with your 88i.
It's been supported since 93g.
So, you need to stay with `<ESC><ESC>`... for autocomplete